# Unable to open file from using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to use apache-poi to open an excel file.

The main code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    HSSFWorkbook readWorkbook =  new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\test.xlsx"));
}
```

Just want to open test.xlsx, but I met some problems: when I run my code, it always enters debug mode, and the snapchart snapshot looks like this:

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: Use `WorkbookFactory.create` instead - your file is an Excel `.xlsx` one